# async/await doesn't work with promisify

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am trying to use [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function, but my code doesn't work. I think I don't understand how promises/promisify work. If I use `new Promise` my code works, but if I use `promisify` it doesn't.

if I run this code:

```
const oembed = require('oembed-auto');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const test = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oembed("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0", function (err, data) {
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.getAllInterests = async () => {
  const data = await test();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};
```

I got expected result:

```
{ html: '<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
  author_url: 'https://www.youtube.com/user/officialpsy',
  thumbnail_url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9bZkp7q19f0/hqdefault.jpg',
  width: 480,
  height: 270,
  author_name: 'officialpsy',
  thumbnail_height: 360,
  title: 'PSY - GANGNAM STYLE(강남스타일) M/V',
  version: '1.0',
  provider_url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
  thumbnail_width: 480,
  type: 'video',
  provider_name: 'YouTube' }
```

If I run this code:

```
const oembed = require('oembed-auto');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const test = () => {
  promisify(oembed)("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0").then((data) => {
    resolve(data);
  });
};

module.exports.getAllInterests = async () => {
  const data = await test();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};
```

Async/await doesn't work and I get:

```
undefined
(node:66423) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: resolve is not defined
(node:66423) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: i mean... `resolve` is undefined in the second case.. Why else would it give you an error stating such

Comment: @KevinB If I change it to `return`, the result is `undefined` without error message `resolve is not defined`

Comment: The two problems are not related.

Comment: I mean, it's not like this is [very well documented](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) or anything. /s The examples in the documentation even directly follow the code logic you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No value is `return`ed from `test`, `resolve` is `undefined` within `.then()`

```
const test = () => promisify(oembed)("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0");
```

```
module.exports.getAllInterests = async () => {
  let data;
  try {
    data = await test();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
  return data;
};
```

```
getAllInterests().then(res => console.log(res), err => console.err(err));
```

Comment: If I change it to `return`, the result is `undefined` without error message `resolve is not defined`

Comment: You don't need the `.then(data => data)` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your test function must be Async, and you just need to use Await on promisify(oembed). Note that you need to use getAllInterests, inside an Async function, in this case I put it inside an async closure. (I tested the code myself, and it's working perfetctly). And it's also nicier to debug and maintain.

```
const oembed = require('oembed-auto');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const test = async () => {
  return await promisify(oembed)("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0");
}

const getAllInterests = async () => {
  const data = await test();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

(async ()=> {
    await getAllInterests();
})();
```

[image: Screenshot with result]